# Lock TFS check-ins when build is failing multiple times in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs, build

Is there any options to lock TFS check-ins when the build is failing or three consequent times in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure about your meaning of `lock TFS check-ins`. If you just want a developer checks in changes that break the build. We **do not have any build in feature to support this integrate with Jenkins**.

However, you can guard some or all of your code base against these problems by creating a gated check-in build definition(TFVC) or pull request(Git) through TFS own build system.

If you are using TFVC, by using Gated build, when developers try to check-in, they are prompted to build their changes. More details please take a look at our [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#gated).

[image]

If you are using Git, you could use pull request and [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops). There is a Build validation setting in branch.

Validate code by pre-merging and building pull request changes

[image]

With using both of above method, you could only check in codes/changes when build succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But basically my requirement is when build (MSBuild) is failing for three consecutive times, developer's code check-in should not trigger an automatic build in Jenkins. It should lock Jenkins from triggering automatic builds. Only once build is green automatic builds should be enabled.